Is a ball the hardest body to approximate by polytopes (in the Banach–Mazur metric)?
$\DeclareMathOperator\conv{conv}\DeclareMathOperator\Vol{Vol}$In the paper "An extremal property of the hypersphere" by Macbeath, the following functionals were introduced (here $n$ is fixed, $N \geq n+1$ and $K \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a convex body)
$$\psi_N (K) = \sup \Big\{ \frac{\Vol(\conv(x_{i})_{i=1}^{N})}{\Vol(K)}: x_1 ,\dotsc, x_N \in K\Big\}$$
and it was proven that they are all minimized for $K = B$, where $B$ is an Euclidean ball; that is, balls are the hardest to approximate by polytopes, in a volumetric sense, in any dimension. His 1 page argument uses Steiner symmetrizations: this functional decreases under these symmetrizations, and is continuous with respect to the Hausdorff metric. Since one can always choose a sequence of symmetrizations that make $K$ converge to an Euclidean ball, we are done.
I define similar functionals (here I assume that $K$ is centered at the origin):
$$\phi_N (K) = \sup \big\{ r>0: \exists x_1 ,\dotsc, x_N \in K,\quad rK \subset \conv(x_i)_{i=1}^{N} \big\}$$
and ask: do these functionals all minimize for $K=B$ as well? i.e, are balls also the hardest to approximate in the Banach–Mazur distance as well?
I expect there to be a silly counterexample to this overly ambitious conjecture, but I couldn't find it.

Do you mean that $K$ is origin-symmetric?

The functionals are defined for every centered convex body. But I don't know the answer even when restricting the domain to origin-symmetric bodies (or any other special class of bodies, for that matter).

What does it mean "centered convex body"?

The center of mass of the body is at the origin.

It seems like in the plane $\phi_3$ is smaller for a square than for a disk. For a disk it should be $1/2$ and for a square I think it is $\sqrt{2}-1$.

@rozu yes, I think I have a proof of your guess for 3 points in a disk and in a square, but it is boring (for a square)

@FedorPetrov Nice. I was quite confident about it because a Monte Carlo experiment coudn't produce a bigger value. But I wasn't able to prove it. The maximizing triangles (2 non-congruent, 8 in total) are all equilateral, so I was hoping to find a nice symmetry argument, but gave up in the end. I only got that these triangles are locally maximizing when sliding the vertices along the boundary of the square. But good to know that there is a proof :)

Let me give a proof of rozu's guess that $\phi_3(D)=1/2$ and $\phi_3(S)=\sqrt{2}-1$ if $D$, $S$ are a disk and a square. This disproves your conjecture.
First of all, for every $K$ and every $N$ the convex hull of every $N$ points in $K$ is contained in the convex hull of $N$ points on the boundary of $K$. Thus, we may suppose that the points $x_1,\dotsc,x_N$ lie on the boundary of $K$.
For a disk $D$, if $x_1x_2x_3$ is a regular triangle, the maximal $r$ such that $rD\subset \triangle x_1x_2x_3$ equals $1/2$. Otherwise, either 0 is not inside $\triangle x_1x_2x_3$ (in this case there is no $r$ for which
$rD\subset \triangle x_1x_2x_3$), or there exist indices $i<j$ such that $\angle x_i0x_j>2\pi/3$, and the distance from 0 to $x_ix_j$ is less then $1/2$, so, the maximal $r$ for which $rD\subset \triangle x_1x_2x_3$ is less then $1/2$.
For a square $S=ABCD$, choose Cartesian coordinates so that the vertices of $S$ have coordinates $(\pm 1,\pm 1)$: $A=(-1,-1)$, $B=(1,-1)$ etc. Consider the square $S_1=A_1B_1C_1D_1$, where $A_1=(\sqrt{2}-1)A=(1-\sqrt{2},1-\sqrt{2})$ etc. I claim that $S_1$ is contained in a triangle with the vertices on the boundary of $S$, but is not contained in the interior of any such triangle. This is equivalent to the desired relation $\phi_3(S)=\sqrt{2}-1$.
Consider the points $K=(3-2\sqrt{2},-1)\in AB$, $L=(-1,3-2\sqrt{2})\in AD$. Then $A_1$ is the midpoint of $KL$, the vectors $\overline{KC}=(2\sqrt{2}-2,2)$, $\overline{B_1C}=(2-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$ are collinear, thus, $B_1$ lies on $KC$, analogously $D_1$ lies on $CL$. This shows that $S_1$ is inscribed to the triangle $\triangle CKL$ (three vertices of the square $S_1$ lie on the sides of $\triangle CKL$ and $C_1$ lies inside it).
Now assume that $S_1$ lies in the interior of a triangle $\triangle PQR$ with $P,Q,R$ lying on the boundary of $S$. One of open intervals $AB,BC,CD,DA$ contains none of $P,Q,R$. Without loss of generality, this is $BC$. Then both closed segments $AB$ and $CD$ contain at least one vertex of $\triangle PQR$, otherwise $\triangle PQR$ clearly does not contain $S_1$. Without loss of generality, $P\in CD$, $Q\in AB$. If $R$ belongs to $AB\cup CD$, without loss of generality $R\in CD$, then $\triangle PQR\subset \triangle CQD$. Without loss of generality, $QA\leqslant QB$, then $Q\in [AK]$, and $CQ$ intersects $S_1$, a contradiction.
So, $R\in AD$. Without loss of generality, $CP\leqslant BQ$. Then $P$ lies between the vertical lines $BC$ and $B_1C_1$, as otherwise $B_1$ and $R$ would be on different sides of $PQ$.  Let $PQ$, $PR$ intersect the diagonal $BD$ at $U,X$ respectively. The order of points on the line $BD$ is $BUB_1D_1XD$. We have $$DP/QB=DU/UB>DB_1/B_1B=\sqrt{2}+1.$$
Next, if $\overline{DX}=(x,-x)$, then $x<2-\sqrt{2}$ and $x/DP+x/DR=RX/RP+XP/RP=1$, thus $$1/DP+1/DR=1/x>\frac1{2-\sqrt{2}}=\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}2.$$
Analogously, $$1/AQ+1/AR>\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}2.$$
Denote $DP=t$, then $t\in [\sqrt{2},2]$ since $P$ lies between the vertical lines $BC$ and $B_1C_1$. We get $1/DR>\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}2-1/t=\frac{t(2+\sqrt{2})-2}{2t}$. Also, $QB<t/(\sqrt{2}+1)=t(\sqrt{2}-1)$, thus $AQ>2-t(\sqrt{2}-1)$ and $1/AR>\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}2-1/AQ=\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}2-\frac1{2-t(\sqrt{2}-1)}=\frac{2+2\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}t}{2(2-t(\sqrt{2}-1))}$. Therefore,
$$
2=AR+DR<\frac{2t}{t(2+\sqrt{2})-2}+\frac{2(2-t(\sqrt{2}-1))}
{2+2\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}t},
$$
but after simplifications (that's quadratic inequality in $t$ after all)  we get that we have equality for $t=\sqrt{2},t=2$ and the opposite inequality for $\sqrt{2}<t<2$, a contradiction.
